# Elasticsearch takes too long to match documents during script scoring

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Index mapping:

```
 {
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 5,
      "number_of_replicas": 2
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 512
      },
      "category": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "source": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I have around 600k documents in this index. I then use a query like that to retrieve similar documents based on vector:

```
{
  script_score: {
    query: { match_all: {} },
    script: {
      source: '(1.0 + cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, \'vector\'))',
      params: {
        query_vector: vectorArray
      }
    },
    min_score: 0
  }
}
```

However, even with 5 shards Elastic takes around 1.3 seconds to complete the request. According to search profiler in Kibana, match phase takes 99.3% of that time.

Is there something I can do to improve my search performance and speed up document matching without changing `script_score` query?